# URI of binary packages on npmjs.com?

Tags: npm

I need to specify a binary package URI, not a npm cache or something. How to figure out what's actual URI npm uses to download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) command with the following syntax:

```
npm view <pkg_name> dist.tarball
```

<sub>**Note:** The `<pkg_name>` part should be substituted with the actual name of the package that you want to find the [tarball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing))'s URI for.</sub>

For instance, running:

```
npm view eslint dist.tarball
```

prints:

> `https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-6.7.0.tgz`

- This shows the URI of the tarball (`.tgz`) for the latest version of `eslint` in the [NPM Registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry).
- This is essentially the same URI that npm utilizes via a [`GET`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) request when you run `npm install <package_name>`.

---

#### Specific package versions:

The syntax for specific versions is:

```
npm view <pkg_name>@<version> dist.tarball
```

<sub>**Note:** Same as previously mentioned; the `<pkg_name>` part should be substituted with the actual name of the package that you want to find. The `<version>` part that follows the `@` symbol should be replaced with the specific version.</sub>

For instance, running:

```
npm view eslint@4.19.0 dist.tarball
```

prints:

> `https://registry.npmjs.org/eslint/-/eslint-4.19.0.tgz`

Comment: Thank you, very comprehensive!!

Answer (score 0):

Also URI could be find in `resolved` field in `package-lock.json`.